# Use values of a list as keys while adding other lists as values for each of the keys

Tags: python

I have 3 lists. I want to use the first that has 2 values as keys to a dictionary while adding the other 2 lists as values for each of the keys.

```
a = ['1','2']
b = ['3','4','5']
c = ['6','7','8']
```

expected result:

```
d = {1:['3','4','5'],2:['6','7','8']}
```

I've tried some combinations of `dict(zip())` but wasn't able to achieve it. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3):

By using `zip(...)` you can get the output you're looking for, but you'll need to create a list with `b` and `c`.

```py
a, b, c = ['1','2'], ['3','4','5'], ['6','7','8']
d = dict(zip(a, (b,c)))
print(d)
```